# Outlook style reply header in Thunderbird 3+

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, reply

Is there any way (or add-on) to include the full reply headers (To: From: etc fields) when replying in Thunderbird?

By default it only places a "On %date%, %user% wrote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply header format is driven by reply_header_* preferences.

Actually the `mailnews.reply_header_type` preference is supposed to accept an additional value 4 to make the format 'user specified' - at least that's what they say in the sources:

```
// 0=no header, 1="<author> wrote:", 2="On <date> <author> wrote:"
// 3="<author> wrote On <date>:", 4=user specified

pref("mailnews.reply_header_type", 2);
```

However I was never able to figure out where the user defined format had to be defined at.

I recommend not bothering with preferences at all and instead using SmartTemplate - it is a great extension that does its job well.

There is a great page in the Mozilla KB about all that:

> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Reply_header_settings

Comment: Tnx, I ended up using the "Change quote and reply format" extension